# Storm Bolt Error Handling Best Practice

Tags: apache-storm

Just wanted to get some ideas on how to detect retried tuples so that they can be added to some kind of dead-letter-queue on their last but unsuccessful retry. I have an idea of how I'd like to handle exceptions/failures in general from this [Google groups thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/storm-user/nxsFPKgaBFQ); in particular the idea of splitting off retriable and non-retriable exceptions.

1. Non-retriable exceptions would be a bug introduced that would not succeed on a replay. I would want to catch these and add the tuple to a dead letter queue immediately. The issue could be analysed and the tuple reprocessed when the bug/issue has been resolved.
2. With retriable exceptions it's not as easy. You can have an intermittent network issue which will succeed on a retry. On the other hand you may have an outage with a downstream service that lasts for hours.

For the latter scenario (retriable exception due to a downstream outage) it would cause the tuple to be replayed X times. I'd like to be able to detect the tuple that fails on the X-th time and then add it to a dead letter queue so that the tuple is not lost forever but replayed when the issue has been resolved. Is there a way to achieve this? I had a look at the Tuple but there doesn't appear to be a member variable for the replay count.

Comment: I would argue that this is opinion based: the scope is clear -- how to handle exceptions in particular framework and common practices are already appeared.